# Store multiple data types in array - Java

Tags: java

so I would like to really shorten this code down possibly to a few lines. I'm extremely new to java so apologies if this question has been asked before.

I would like to store all the fields I have declared in my Main class in an array, but each are a different data type so I'm not sure how I would go about this. And then I would like to print corresponding field labelled with its specific datatype. It would ideally look something like : "My [datatype] is: [value stored]" for each declared field that I have declared. I imagine it condenses all the repeated print statements to one line based on the size of the array by using a for loop and looping through the size of the array, but am new to Java and am not particularly familiar with for loops and ranges. My code:

```
class Main {
    static int a = 5;
    static float b = 130.1f;
    static double c = 55.5;
    static boolean d = true;
    static char e = 'h';
    static String f =  "Bg";

    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println("My Number is "+ a);
        System.out.println("My Float is "+ b);
        System.out.println("My Double is "+ c);
        System.out.println("My Boolean is "+ d);
        System.out.println("My Char is "+ e);
        System.out.println("My String is "+ f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To store objects of different types in an array, list or what ever you have to use their common base class. Primitive data types do not have a common base class but their class counterparts. Instead of declaring a string array just declase an `Object[]`. "But 5 or 'h' is not a class?!" That's true but the data is automatically boxed in the correspondig wrapper class. And what is important, too - even if the array stores only objects of class `Object` the concrete class is still available and can be retrieved at runtime to print the wanted information.

BTW - the code could look like this:

```
Object[] args = { 5, 130.1f, 55.5, true, 'h', "Bg" };
        
for (Object obj : args) {
    System.out.println(String.format("My [%s] is: [%s]", obj.getClass().getSimpleName(), obj));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Main {
    static int a = 5;
    static float b = 130.1f;
    static double c = 55.5;
    static boolean d = true;
    static char e = 'h';
    static String f = "Bg";

    private static List arr = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d, e, f));

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (Object o : arr)
            System.out.println("My " + o.getClass().getName() + " is " + o);
    }
}
```